# limit of iteration for nonlinear functions in OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I wonder to know ho we can define the limit of iteration for solving nonlinear functions in OpenModelica? is it possible to log the average of iteration per time step or number of iterations per time step?

Comment: First of all, what is meant by a nonlinear function? Do you mean a Modelica function that evaluates an explicit nonlinear equation, e.g. y = f(x), and implemanted as a function? or simply a nonlinear equation in the equation section?

Comment: I think the first one, I mean nonlinear function such as the model of a nonlinear inductor in an RLC circuit or model of a surge arrester (nonlinear resistance)

Comment: It is not straightforward to recognize whether the nonlinear equation will be solved as a stand-alone equation or will land in a DAE system and solved within a DAE solver. If the non-linear equation (system) going to be solved say using a Gaus-Newton iteration, at every time step, the solution at the previous time step is going to be taken as an initial guess. Usually Gauss-Newton iteration would not take more than two iterations to converge to the solution at the actual time step. Also the so called tearing method could be involved in case a large-scale nonlinear equation system is resulted.

Comment: Thanks, Atiyah,  during simulation sometimes we face this message "Warning: maximal number of iteration reached but no root found Warning: ". how can we change the maximal number of iteration?

Comment: You are welcome. This has to do with the root finding algorithms for evaluating state-events, i.e. time point where an event indicator change its sign.

Comment: This implies that the root-finding algorithm is hanging in a so-called chattering situation, I.e. event indicator switchs sign after every iteration without being able to evaluate the zero-crossing, I.e.  the time event precisely in a numerical sense.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to limit the number of iterations of the nonlinear solvers in OpenModelica ([you can limit many other iteration types though](https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/1.16/simulationflags.html))

To see the execution times, counts, and maximum time to solve the system (to get average, divide total time with execution count), enable Profiling (under the Simulation Flags). Note that profiling adds some overhead to the total simulation times especially if you have many small systems you profile. You may need to press the refresh button in the transformational debugger window that pops up if the information isn't populated automatically.